# Trigger function when input field is changed programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a slider which changes the value of the input fields named 'workload1' and 'workload2'.
Having adjusted the slider, the form 'test-form1' should be submitted. (I do not have any submit button, and all my filtering options work with event listeners)

After submitting the form, the page is reloaded, and the slider has to be set to the values the user has manually adjusted. So if someone moves the slider, the page is reloaded and the slider handles are at the same position as where the user has moved them.
In order to make this happen, I pass the 'workload_min' and 'workload_max' back to my template 'myfile.html'.

Now the question is, how can I trigger the trigger the event listener when the slider handles are moved?

I have tried with `dispatchEvent(event)`, however, since the values are passed back to the template, the `dispatchEvent(event)` will be triggered again and again, in an endless reloading of the page.

I have also tried with a simple `addEventListener('input', function ())` but the change of the input field, through movement of the slider handles, is not detected.

Does someone know how to handle this problem?

html:

```
<input form="test-form1" type="text" name="workload1" id="workload1" readonly="readonly">
<input form="test-form1" type="text" name="workload2" id="workload2" readonly="readonly">
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

script:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 20,
      step:20,
      max: 100,
      values: {% if workload_min %}
                  [{{ workload_min}}, {{workload_max }}]
              {% else %}
                  [ 20, 100 ]
              {% endif %},
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#workload1" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]+"%");
        $( "#workload2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]+"%");
      }
    });
    
    $( "#workload1" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "%" );
    $( "#workload2" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + "%" );
});


var workload1 = document.getElementById('workload1')

var event = new Event('input')

workload1.addEventListener('input', function() {
    form.submit()
})

workload1.dispatchEvent(event)
```

view.py:

```
def djangoFunction(request):
    workload_min = request.POST.get('workload1')
    workload_max = request.POST.get('workload2')

    # do some filtering and preprocessing
    context = {'workload_min: workload_min',
               'workload_max: workload_max'}
    return render(request, 'myfile.html', context)
```

Comment: I don't see the `dispatchEvent` statement in the code that you have shared.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I just added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery UI Slider documentation specifies a [change](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) function that can be added to the configuration object. This function will get called whenever the user changes the value of the slider by moving one of its handles. We can use this function to submit the form.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    change: function() {
      console.log(`min: ${$('#workload1').val()}`);
      console.log(`max: ${$('#workload2').val()}`);
      console.log('submit form now');
      // form.submit();
    },
    range: true,
    min: 20,
    step: 20,
    max: 100,
    values: [40, 80],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#workload1").val(ui.values[0] + "%");
      $("#workload2").val(ui.values[1] + "%");
    }
  });

  $("#workload1").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + "%");
  $("#workload2").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + "%");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input form="test-form1" type="text" name="workload1" id="workload1" readonly="readonly">
<input form="test-form1" type="text" name="workload2" id="workload2" readonly="readonly">
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```